# Math command fails to produce output on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

Completely new to python, I'm trying to get the math packages included in anaconda to work.

If I run a math command in IP Notebook, I get the right answer:

[image]

But under the same settings, if I run the equivalent command on a `.py` file on PyCharm nothing happens:

[image]
[image]

It can be a very, very basic misunderstanding of how to run code in `.py` on the console within PyCharms, but I don't know the answer.

Comment: You probably don't have [the correct interpreter configured in PyCharm.](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of expressions in a Python script are not normally printed - this is a feature of the interpreter and the notebook. In a script it would not make much sense to compute x * y and do nothing with it.

Try this instead: `print(3j * 9)`